# Coefficients of powers of the theta function

Tags: number-theory, special-functions, power-series, modular-forms, theta-functions

Let $q=\exp(2 \pi i z)$ and $$\theta(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty q^{n^2}.$$

Now, I shall show that the powers of $\theta$ are given by

$$\theta(z)^r = \sum_{n=0}^\infty S_r(n) q^n$$

where $S_r(n)$ denotes to the number of $z\in \mathbb{Z}^r$ s.t. $||z||^2=n$.

Who can help me to show that these $S_r(n)$ are the right coefficients for $\theta^r$?

Comment: It is correct. I recommend that you write out several terms of the original and square it by hand ($r=2$), and maybe write a simple computer program to find $S_2(n)$ for small $n,$ or just see http://oeis.org/A004018

Comment: Again, carefully multiply out $\theta^3 = \theta \cdot \theta^2$ and compare http://oeis.org/A005875

Comment: four squares  http://oeis.org/A000118 In each case, there is a link to a table by T. D. Noe with $n$ and $S_r(n)$ side by side.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing deeper here then the multiplication of power series,

$$(\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty x^{n^2})^r=(\sum_{a=-\infty}^\infty x^{a^2})(\sum_{b=-\infty}^\infty x^{b^2})(\sum_{c=-\infty}^\infty x^{c^2})...=(\sum_{a=-\infty}^\infty\sum_{b=-\infty}^\infty\sum_{c=-\infty}^\infty x^{a^2+b^2+c^2..})$$
$$\text{ Which is just a sum over all ordered pairs (a,b,c,....)}$$

$$\text{Where each member is an integer ranging from negative infinity to positive infinity}$$
$$\text{ so that, $\theta(x)^r$}=\sum_{(a,b,c..)}x^{a^2+b^2+c^2...}$$
$$\text{ with the sum running over all integer pairs $(a,b,c,..)$}$$
$$\text{ Also note that every term will be of the form $x^n$, with $0\leq n$} $$

$$\text{Sense each exponent is a sum of squares with each square being positive}$$
$$\text{ So that means we have, $\theta(x)^r=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n$}$$
$$\text{ For some suitable coeffients $c_n$}$$
$$\text{ Also realize that the exponents originally were, $a^2+b^2+c^2...$}$$
$$\text{ So that the nth exponent will correspond to $n=a^2+b^2+c^2..$}$$
$$\text{ Which means that each coeiffient will correspond to the number of ways $n=a^2+b^2+c^2...$}$$
$$\text{ Where the only constraints on $(a,b,c,..)$ are the previous ones}$$
$$\text{ Namely $(a,b,c,...)$ be distinct integer pairs where each elements is an integer}$$
$$\text{ We can also just constrain the integer pairs to be distinct for each coeiffient}$$
Because they can't be the same for any different exponents n and j, because this would imply $n=j$